# How to loop over three different data collections effectively in Python?

Tags: python, performance, list

What would be the best/fastest way to accomplish the following: I have a big file I need to update. I won't load it into memory but read it line by lien like this.

```
with open(self.f, "rb") as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            l = line.strip().split(',')
```

For each line there are potentially two different update scenarios. That is, two large lists/tuples with the update information. For each line I have to check if, let's say `l[0]`, is meeting a condition in list one, if not check for another condition in list two. I am wondering what would be wise here as I am potentially running into performance issues. My first idea was to delete the item from the list/tuple if it was matched so the list becomes smaller and smaller with runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To test for membership against a series of values, use a `set` instead of a list.

Like dictionary lookups, set membership tests are O(1) operations. Cheap, independent of the size of the set.

```
set_one = {'some_value', 'some_other_value', ...}

# ...
if l[0] in set_one:
    # do something.
```

If you needed to map values, use a dictionary:

```
dict_one = {'some_value': 'item1', 'some_other_value': 'item2', ...}

# ...
if l[0] in dict_one:
    item = dict_one[l[0]]
```

This all depends on exactly what kind of lookups you are trying to *do*; many different kinds of lookups can be made very efficient with the right data structures. Looping over large lists for every line in a file is usually *not* the best option.

Comment: Plus, you don't have to remove anything from the set once it has been used—just leaving it in is cheaper.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff: yup, that is why I explicitly mentioned that lookup cost is independent from the size of the set.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff unless for some reason that once a match is found, it should no longer be considered a match...

Comment: @JasonOrendorff: That said, removing an item carries an O(1) cost as well. But removing items for the sake of speeding up lookups makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I do need the item though if the membership test returns True. I guess I should just use a list comprehension to get the item then?

Comment: @LarsVegas: If `l[0] in some_set` is `True`, then `l[0]` *is* the item.

Comment: Well, my data looks a bit different. As I said I wanna update the file, so `l[0]` is used as a filter to then change l[3] with an item from the list that could look like this: `[(a,b),(a,b,),...]` where `a` matches `l[0]`.

Comment: Then you need to make that *clear* in your question. You'd need to use a different structure for those; a dictionary mapping `a` to `b` would have the same performance metrics as a `set` for membership testing, but would also give you access to the value `b`.